# Drupal 7 Feeds to grab images inside <image></image> tags

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-7, feed

I have a feed link with in the following format

```
<item>
<title>Lorum ipsum</title>
<teaser>Lorum ipsum</teaser>
<description>Lorum ipsum</description>
<link>http://www.example.com/article/?ad=1</link>
<image>http://www.example.com/image/123456/248x500?.cached</image>
<author>noreply@example.com</author>
<pubDate>Wed, 2 May 2012 14:22:24 +0200</pubDate>
<guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.example.comARTICLE12345678</guid>
</item>
```

I am trying to grab the images inside the   tags to a separate field in Drupal, but so far nothing is working. Tried many tutorials but except image everything is saved.

What can be the solution? 
Many thanks

Sathish

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom PHP code to generate this feed, you can embed the image inside the `description` tag.

```
$description = "Lorum ipsum" . "<br />";
$description .= check_plain("<img alt='' src='PATH_TO_IMAGE' />");
```

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Comment: Thank You Muhammad - I tried modules for feeds - aggregator/feedd Grabber etc - now started working on custom PHP :)